# Image click after animation

Tags: android, click, android-animation

I have this strange issue. I have an image which I rotate about a fixed point using `rotateAnimation`.

I have handled the click event when the user clicks the images as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageView1:
        finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Next.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        }
}
```

The problem I face is that, after I rotate the image, the click event is not triggered when I click the image, but is triggered when I click the position where the image was at first.

I know I must be missing something basic here but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Building animations on Android is a very difficult task. The documentation is not only incomplete but inaccurate quite often. Animations also do not function in a logical, but completely arbitrary manner. I'm afraid the only solution is hours of wasted time through try and test - of course that is until the Android team breaks things again in a new release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Animation`s do not cause the animating `View` to change position or size. They only show such transformations without affecting any of the properties of the `View`. Hence the behavior seen by you.

In case you want to actually move/resize the `View` object, implement `AnimationListener` and perform the operation on `onAnimationEnd`.

Comment: thanks @rajesh.. but wouldnt the event be triggered at the end of the animation instead of image click?

Comment: By operation, I meant moving/resizing the `View`, so that you see it where you expect it to be. I did not mean implementing the `onClick` behavior in `onAnimationEnd`.

Comment: i am trying to modify the layout params using the code below       `android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.topMargin = ServerImage.getTop()-100;
params.bottomMargin = ServerImage.getBottom()-100;
params.rightMargin = ServerImage.getRight()-100;
params.leftMargin = ServerImage.getLeft()-100;
ServerImage.setLayoutParams(params);` but it shows no difference :(

Comment: Please post it as a new question as it is unrelated to the original question.