# setFillAfter not working?

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I am using this code:

```
  public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 final   LinearLayout answerLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.answerlayout);

    Button slideAnswer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerslide);
    slideAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0,-400, 0,0 );   
                slide.setDuration(1000);   
                slide.setFillAfter(true);   
                slide.setFillEnabled(true);
                answerLayout.startAnimation(slide);  

        }
    });
}
```

I just want that the answerLayout translate to thenew position and stay at that place and work normally.But it is not . Can someone please spot the error and correct me.Or give a different technique for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What do you expect and what is the behavior? `Animation` will not alter the actual properties of the `View`.

Comment: Then how could I alter the position of the view with this type of animation

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10533065/1321873